# How to open a new word document from outlook add-ins?

Tags: javascript, outlook, visual-studio-2015, office365, outlook-addin

I created an office outlook add-ins application. In my add-ins I have a button '**open word document**' to open new Microsoft word document with **word add-ins** in locally and want to save it in Microsoft  **oneDrive**

After searching some document I found a code that I tried but not working ..

after click on '**open word document**' called a function **openWordAddin()**

```
function openWordAddin() {

        var url = 'ms-word:ofe|u|' + 'document.docx';
         window.open(url, 'myDoc', '', false);
    }
```

it open a new tab in browser but not word document. can anyone help me pls..